# Commutation of $J^2$ and $J_i$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, commutator

For the Hermitian operators $\hat{J_1},\hat{J_2},\hat{J_3}$ that satisfies the commutation relations
$$[\hat{J_1},\hat{J_2}]=i\hbar\hat{J_3},$$
$$[\hat{J_2},\hat{J_3}]=i\hbar\hat{J_1},$$
$$[\hat{J_3},\hat{J_1}]=i\hbar\hat{J_2},$$

and defining $\hat{J^2}=\hat{J_1}^2+\hat{J_2}^2+\hat{J_3}^2$, how can it be shown that
$[\hat{J^2},\hat{J_1}]=0$?

Comment: Use the fact that $\hat{J}_i^2 = \hat{J}_i\hat{J}_i$ and $[\hat{A}\hat{B},\hat{C}] = \hat{A}[\hat{B},\hat{C}] + [\hat{A},\hat{C}]\hat{B}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any operators $A$ and $B$,
$$
 [A^2,B]=A[A,B]+[A,B]A. 
$$

This property is useful do compute $[J_i^2,J_j]$, where $i,j=1,2,3$, as shown below:
\begin{eqnarray}
[J_1^2,J_1]&=&0,\\
[J_2^2,J_1]&=&J_2[J_2,J_1]+[J_2,J_1]J_2=-i\hbar J_2J_3-i\hbar J_3J_2\\
[J_3^2,J_1]&=&J_3[J_3,J_1]+[J_3,J_1]J_3=i\hbar J_3J_2+i\hbar J_2J_3
\end{eqnarray}